# MySql : How to delete multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

How should I delete those two rows by using user_email and note_name only?
Please help

thank you

Comment: `delete from t where user_email = 'asdf@gmail.com' and note_name = 'asdf';`

Comment: Instead of writing a delete statement directly build a select statement with the where clause and update the where clause till the time you get the intended data then change that select statement to a delete statement. This will make your work easy. Because one can experiment with a select statement but not a delete statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below delete script-

```
delete from your_table_name where user_email = 'asdf@....' and note_name = 'adsf'
```

**Note:** This will also delete other rows if there any matching for the conditions.